# What is the $L^2$ space of sections of a vector bundle?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

The vector bundle in question can be a holomorphic line bundle with a hermitian metric.
Given $\mathcal{L}$ a holomorphic line bundle with transition functions $g_{ij}$ a section is defined as a collection ${h_i}$ such that $h_i=g_{ij}h_j$. Or is another definition of sections better for this purpose?
Oh i should probably mention that this is on a compact Riemann surface.

Comment: This is the vector space of [sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(fiber_bundle)) $s\colon M\to L$, where $L$ is the bundle over $M$, with $\int_M \|s\|^2 <+\infty$ for $h$ induced by the chosen (Hermitian) metric

Comment: Using the letter $h$ for your section is not the most convenient, as most references will use $h$ to refer to the hermitian metric. So how does the hermitian metric give you the square of the length of your section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L \to \Sigma$ be your holomorphic line bundle. This bundle admits, by a partition of unity argument and the local trivialization of the bundle, a smooth bundle metric, lets call it $g_L$. Given a global section $s:\Sigma \to L$, we define
$$
|s|^2=g_{L}(s,s).
$$
This is well defined and we can just integrate it:
$$
||s||_{L^2}^2=\int_{\Sigma}|s|^2 d\mathrm{vol} 
$$

In more detail:
So given a trivialization atlas $\{(U_i,\phi_i) \}$ of $L$, this section looks locally like
$$
s:U_i \to U_i \times  \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto (z,u(z))
$$
and a local metric looks like
$$
g_i:U_i\times \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R},(z,u_1,u_2) \mapsto u_1 \overline{u_2}.
$$
You can glue these local metrics together using a partition of unity argument to build a (global) metric $g_L$.

To see that this is well defined for your section, use the fact that for a hermitian vector bundle, the transition functions can be chose unitary, in your case: $g_{ij} \in U(1)$. But you see that every local metric is invariant under $u(1)$ transformations:
$$
e^{i\phi}u_1 \overline{e^{i\phi}u_2}=u_1 \overline{u_2}
$$
and so is a combination of them: The (global) metric! Now, this gives therefore a well-defined function for a section $s: \Sigma \to L$ in the form
$$
|s|^2: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}, z \mapsto g_L(s,s) .
$$
This is now something you can integrate over $\Sigma$. Now, every section with finite $L^2$ norm is in $L^2(\Gamma(L))$ (the $L^2$-space of sections of $L$).

A good exercise is to check what this would look like for the space of sections of the trivial bundle $\Sigma \times \mathbb{C} \to \Sigma$ for a (non-)compact Riemann surface. Hint: It is the ordinary $L^2$ norm
$$
\int_{\Sigma} |u(z)|^2 d\mathrm{vol}.
$$
I just added non-compact to allow non-trivial, holomorphic sections.

Comment: @Mariano The usual setting is talking about $L^2$ holomorphic sections on a non-compact RS (perhaps one with singular points).

Comment: Since you said holomorphic line bundle, I just assumed you meant holomorphic sections as well.  
Of course, this construction, modolu some discussion, carries over the meromorphic sections as well.

Comment: This should carry over to sections with much less regularity than only meromorphic sections. Locally in a chart over $U$ you can do the very same stuff as in the$\mathbb{R}^n$-analog, like taking the closure w.r.t. the norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$. For some applications one may want a Hilbert space of $L^2$-sections in that bundle.